# Default instruments for FL Studio 12?

Tags: instruments, daw, fl-studio

I can not find this anywhere on their website or forums. I understand that FL 12 has a lot of presets and whatnot for the oscillators, and a lot of synth sounds, but what does it have for real instruments (eg. piano, violin, mixed strings, guitar, harpsichord, etc.)? Before buying or installing FL studio I would like to know what instruments it has since the music I make is "real instrument" sounding music that I use a DAW for so that I don't have to hire 10 people to play instruments for me, and can just create it solo, not really synth sounding stuff like Alan Walker does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous sounds You can get from the FL Studio's basic installation.

In version 12.1.2, You can find a fine piano on `Fl-keys` generator (in the plugin browser, go to `Installed > generators > Fruity`). There are many piano sounds, through which You can list by clicking on the `<` and `>` arrows on the top right corner of the `FL Keys` window.

The browser is usually on the left part of the software's window, but You can enable it by going to `View` menu, and selecting the `Browser` option.

[image: FL Keys generator]

For a nice bass, You can get the `FL Slayer` generator (the same path as for the FL Keys, or You can click on the `+` button and select it from the `Physical modeling` sub-menu.

[image: FL Slayer generator]

There are many other instruments somewhere inside FL Studio, and for the ones that are not, I am sure You can find them in some of the free VST plugin sets (like [this one from Native Instruments - links to native-instruments.com](https://www.native-instruments.com/en/specials/free-vst-plugins/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=sea&utm_content=paid&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIod_l5oeo2QIV04eyCh2QUgTqEAAYASAAEgKnqvD_BwE)

Hope this helps!